# How can I identify threads that are running the same method in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am making a python program that should load a webpage and search for a cookie. I have a method called `startsearch` and I want it to run at the same time in 3 different threads as below.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = startsearch, args=(x, )).start()
    Thread(target = startsearch, args=(x, )).start()
    Thread(target = startsearch, args=(x, )).start()
```

How would I kill a specific thread then? I basically want to kill the thread once the cookie has been found but since each thread is the same, how to identify them?

Comment: Can you not have the thread kill itself?

Comment: You should rephrase the question: how do you terminate a thread.  Needless to say, there is good documentation on threads such as https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html.  I suggest you study it

Comment: Let see if I understand it correctly: 3 threads are looking for the same thing, if one of them found it, you want to kill the other two, correct?